# BCC emails not working - is there a log I can view?

Tags: email, logs

We're using Civi 4.7.12 on Joomla 3.6.2. 
Our Society has subgroups which need to be alerted when a contribution comes in for them. We have set the group contact's email address in the bcc field of the relevant contribution page. The contribution is accepted and the donor gets an emailed receipt but the bcc isn't being received. We have tried using an inhouse address as the bcc recipient and that doesn't work either.

Our SMTP mailer does not require authentication.

Is there a log in Civi of mail being sent? Any help would be very welcome.

Regards
Claire

Comment: Thanks. We did that and there are no headings for bcc or cc, and no sign of the bcc or cc emails having been sent. However, we now know that the bcc and cc emails are working for Event confirmations, and for an email message within Civi, so it must be the Contribution form but we can't see it.
We have tried using both SMTP and Mail in Civi, the latter at the suggestion of our ISP. The pages which do work don't mind who gets the bcc (e.g., <someone>@gmail.com works). Does a Contribution page have tighter controls? Can it only go to an email address within our domain? This is causing real angst

Answer (score 2):

The Administer Screen *Settings - Outbound Mail* gives you the option to enable *Redirect to Database*. (You can navigate to the screen with Administer -> System Settings -> Outbound Email (SMTP/SendMail), or with `civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1`)The mail is spooled to the table `civicrm_mailing_spool`.

*Update:* In case of the use of **cc:** and **bcc:** it is a bit tricky. I just did a short search in the code and found that, when the Pear mailing library is installed, the **bcc** and the **cc:** are removed from the Headers and added to the list of recipients. [CRM-19173](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19173) explains the reason. So in the spool table, they can be found in the `recipient_email` appended to the list of email addresses, but not in the `headers`.

See the code at [Mail.php](https://github.com/twomice/civicrm-core/blob/d39f2583c82d37966c07057440eee2b4831b7210/CRM/Utils/Mail.php) line 260.

Comment: But that shouldn't mean that CC and BCC recipients don't get the email, just that they're not in <header> array, but added to list of recipients